# Vector addition not working properly

Tags: python, floating-point

I made a class in python for vectors and vector addition; however, it doesn't seem to produce the results that I expected.

A vector with the direction of pi (radians) or 180 (degrees) and the magnitude of 1 plus a vector with the direction of pi*2 (radians) or 0/360 (degrees) and the magnitude of 1 should make a vector of (0, 0), correct? However, I'm getting strange results from the code.

> (-1.5707963267948966, 1.2246467991473532e-16)

This is the result I get from the above vector addition I described.

And here's my code:

```
import math

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, direction, magnitude, directionType="degrees"):
        if directionType=="degrees":
            direction = math.radians(direction)
        self.direction = direction
        self.magnitude = magnitude

    def __add__(self, other):
        x = (math.sin(self.direction) * self.magnitude) + (math.sin(other.direction) * other.magnitude)
        y = (math.cos(self.direction) * self.magnitude) + (math.cos(other.direction) * other.magnitude)
        magnitude = math.hypot(x, y)
        direction = 0.5 * math.pi - math.atan2(y, x)
        return (direction, magnitude)



v1 = Vector(math.pi, 1, directionType="radians")
v2 = Vector(math.pi*2, 1, directionType="radians")

print v1+v2
```

Comment: You've got a magnitude of (approximately) 0. Isn't that exactly what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.22e-16 is a very small number. If you don't like seeing it, round your number to a sensible precision and it will be zero. I wouldn't expect the angle to be predictable, in this case it seems to be pi/2. An example of rounding to 10 decimal places:

```
angle, magnitude= v1+v2
magnitude = round(magnitude, 10)
result = (angle, magnitude)
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks to be working correctly.  Please see [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic*](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf).

I thought there was a digest version of it published somewhere, but I can't find it.